# C++ pointer assignment and arrow member selection operator

Tags: c++, class, pointers

What would be the difference between doing :

```
MyClass * ptr = new MyClass;
```

and

```
MyClass * ptr = &MyClass;
```

and

```
MyClass * ptr = NULL;
```

etc etc.

and then doing `ptr->func1();`

What's the difference? Which ones should I use? How do I use them?

Comment: way too broad. Read a C++ book.

Comment: I'm reading C++ Primer right now but i couldn't find anything. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming `MyClass` is been defined as say something like:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void func1();
};
```

then of your 3 suggestions only the first is really fully valid.

`new MyClass` attempts to create an instance of MyClass and if successful returns a pointer to the instance, which you assign to `ptr`. Calling `ptr->func1()` uses the member function on that instance as you would expect.

The second:

```
MyClass * ptr = &MyClass;
```

is not valid C++ and will not compile.

The third option:

```
MyClass * ptr = NULL;
```

is valid but calling `ptr->func1()` after that is invoking undefined behavior. This will compile fine but would show up as a runtime problem.

`NULL` is just the value `0`. If for some reason you're working directly with pointers than you should make sure that a pointer that is not pointing to an object is always set to this value. C++11 has [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) which is harder to accidentally use incorrectly, so would be preferred unless you need to support older C++ standards.
You can then check if the pointer is valid with a simple `if` statement:

```
if(ptr)
{
    ptr->func1();
}
```

Modern idiomatic C++ though rarely involves this kind of pointer manipulation.
Using automatic variables such as:

```
MyClass myObject;
myObject.func1();
```

is generally preferred when possible as it is normally more efficient and safer than using dynamic allocation.

If you do need dynamic allocation then it is normally preferred to use smart pointers to take care of the tricky details for you.
If you are using C++11 then you will have access to a [rich set of smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). If not then you can still use the [smart pointers from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Try not to use the first, use:

```
MyClass a;
```

whenever you can (and if you really need dynamic allocation use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

The second won't compile.

The third will define a pointer and initialize it with a null pointer.  Consider [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead of `NULL`.
Also `boost::optional` or [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) for an optional object (it can be there, but need not).

Comment: "specifically if you ..."? That's the only use for `optional`.